# update parent by iframe ajax.beginform

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

i am trying to update the parent div, by an ajax form in iframe, but not working. 
It must change FORM1 content but instead, iframe redirects.
 is there a way?

```html
    <div id="FORM1">
    <iframe>
    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Spos", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "FORM1" })) %>
    <% { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    
    ....
    <% } %>
    </iframe/>
    </div>
```